# Is it correctly understood that ROC/AUC cannot be calculated without flexible criterion value?

Tags: classification, roc, auc

I have a proprietary predictor that simply gives me a binary output. Let's say that it is detecting faulty units. In a set where 27 units are faulty and 76 units are working the predictor correctly identifies 4 units as defect and predicts that all other units are working.

This gives a high specificity (1) and low sensitivity (0.15). I originally wanted to create a ROC and calculate the AUC compared to another method that has a continuous criterion value. However, the more I read the less plausible that seems to be.

Is it correct that I cannot calculate an AUC as a ROC is meaningless with a fixed criterion? If yes would it make sense to plot the proprietary predictor as a single point together with the ROC for the continuous method?

There is slightly more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925290/r-confusion-matrix-indicates-classification-method-1-is-best-roc-indicates-met?noredirect=1#comment96627922_54925290) though that may cause more confusion than clarity.

Thanks for reading through my post and all feedback is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUC is meaningless with a fixed criterion because it attempts to summarize the performance of your classifier over the full ROC operating range when you know well in advance that you only have access to a single point in that range.

The good news is that the AUC might not be the right metric for the job anyway. The AUC is a good metric to compare classifiers without regard to a specific application domain. It tells you how the two classifiers perform *overall*.

However, on a given domain, it is possible that neither of the two classifiers dominates across the full ROC range: one of the two classifiers might have a better TPR at lower FPR while the other classifier dominates at a higher FPR. Here's an example from google images:

[image: ROC curves where neither dominates across the full range]

When this happens, it is not always the case that the classifier with the better AUC really performs better on your application domain: it all depends on the real world costs of both kinds of misclassifications (false positives and false negatives).

I see two options, one simpler, and one better:

1. **The simple option: Pick a single point on the continuous criterion classifier's ROC curve.** Your fixed criterion classifier gives you a (FPR, TPR) pair. Lookup the true positive rate of the continuus criterion classifier for that same false positive rate, and compare these two points. Which of the two classifiers performs best at this fixed specificity? Alternatively, pick any other point on the ROC curve and use a summary metric like the f-measure.
2. **The better option: base your evaluation on misclassification costs.** Determine the true costs of false positives and false negatives on your application domain. Given these costs, estimate the expected cost of a prediction for the fixed criterion classifier, and do the same for every point along the continuous criterion classifier's ROC curve. Compare the best cost you could achieve for the continuous criterion classifier to the cost you obtained for the fixed criterion classifier.